# Getting another tables data to show in drop down list Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I am making a form to capture a users driving activities for the day. I have 2 tables. A `vehicle` table and my main `vehiclelog` table. the `vehicle` table shall contain a list of details about a vehicle. In my main (`vehiclelog`) form, the user will have to enter a name, then select a vehicle from the drop down list that will pull the `reg_number` column and display it in that drop down.
I have the following code but it returns an `Attempt to read property "id" on string` error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

my controller:

```
class MaintenanceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $energy = Maintenance::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        $cars = Vehicle::where('id', 1)->pluck('reg_number', 'car_model');
        return view('admin.vmaintenance', compact('energy','cars'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $energy = new Maintenance;
        $cars = Vehicle::all();

        $energy->smsstaff_key = $request->input('technician');
        $cars->reg_number = $request->input('vehicle_id');
        $energy->log_dt = $request->input('log_dt');
        $energy->admin_time = $request->input('admin_time');
        $energy->driving_time = $request->input('driving_time');
        $energy->work_time = $request->input('work_time');
        $energy->jobcard_count = $request->input('jobcard_count');
        $energy->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
        $energy->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');


        $energy->save();
        return redirect('/vmaintenance')->with('success', 'data added');
    }
}
```

My models:

Vehicle model:

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'vehicle';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
   
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Energy model:

```
class Energy extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table='energystores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'energystore_key';
    
    use HasFactory;
}
```

the dropdown in the view:

```
  <label>Select Vehicle</label>
  <select name="vehicle_id" >
  @foreach($cars as $car)
  <option value="{{ $car->id }}">{{ $car->reg_number }}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
```

Comment: When you use `pluck()` there is a key-value array returned instead of a collection of models. try to dump `$cars`. (if you remove the pluck function and replace it wit `get()`, it will work).

Comment: is all the other code to fetch those details of the cars from the other table correct though?

Comment: @nivan34 as i commented: `$cars = Vehicle::where('id', 1)->get();` . I guess the where is only for testing? this way there will only be one car selected

Comment: @Pradeep, I still get the same error. Is there any other way I could accomplish this?

Comment: @GertB. okay this works!! but it only shows 1 as you said. is there any way to make it show all?

Comment: @nivan34 remove `where('id', 1)->` so `Vehicle::get();`

Comment: All records `Vehicle::pluck('reg_number', 'id')->all()`

Comment: @GertB. Great okay it works!! Just does not store in my DB under the `vehicle_id` column. I think that is because I have `$cars->reg_number = $request->input('vehicle_id');` and not `$vehicle->reg_number = $request->input('vehicle_id');`

Comment: you never call the `save()` function on `$cars` and `$cars` is an object collection . the variable name doesn't matter

Comment: I changed `$cars->reg_number = $request->input('vehicle_id');` to `$energy->vehicle_id = $request->input('vehicle_id');` and it does save to my db, but it shows the ID in the table entry, not the `reg_number`

Comment: The option value is the id, change that to the reg_number too

Comment: @GertB. You are a life saver! I was stuck on this for hours!!

Answer (score -1):

instead of:

`$cars = Vehicle::where('id', 1)->pluck('reg_number', 'car_model');`

use this:

`$cars = Vehicle:pluck('reg_number', 'id');`

Comment: what about this: ` $cars = Vehicle:select('id', 'reg_number')->get()`